# how to make FTP connection with require implicit FTP over TLS in PHP

Tags: ftp, ssl

I want to connect FTP with encryption require implicit FTP over TLS using PHP code.

I have tried for encryption with Use Plain FTP, it works but encryption require implicit FTP over TLS not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below snippet:

```
<?php

// set up basic ssl connection
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

echo ftp_pwd($conn_id); // /

// close the ssl connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```